# How do I overlap figure axes and extend one axes title across two axes in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have a figure that includes four plots. All y-axis are Temperature and the two x-axis are Time1 and Time2. I am stacking and aligning all four plots into a 2x2 figure using the `patchwork` package and `plot_layout()` function in R. Since, all y-axes are the same variable, I only want to show one y-axis title on the left side of the plot, but I can't figured out how to do this. I also want to cover-up the y-axes on the two plots in the right column, but when I move the figures, the right column overlaps the left column (I want the opposite).

Here is an example of what I have done so far.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(20), y1 = rnorm(20))
df2 <- data.frame(x2 = rnorm(20), y2 = rnorm(20))
df3 <- data.frame(x3 = rnorm(20), y3 = rnorm(20))
df4 <- data.frame(x4 = rnorm(20), y4 = rnorm(20))

p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
           plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))

p2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x2, y = y2)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))

p3 <- ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = x3, y = y3)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Time1") +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(-0.5,0,0,0),"cm"))

p4 <- ggplot(data = df4, aes(x = x4, y = y4)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Time2") +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(-0.5,0,0,0),"cm"))

p5 <- p1/p2/p3/p4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, heights = c(1,1))
p5
```

Which produces this figure:
[image]

However, I would ultimately like the figure to look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `facet_grid`? We'll need to do some data cleanup first though:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
libary(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(Sample = 1, Time1 = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))
df2 <- data.frame(Sample = 1, Time2 = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))
df3 <- data.frame(Sample = 2, Time1 = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))
df4 <- data.frame(Sample = 2, Time2 = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20)) 

data <- bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "df[0-9]"))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-y,-Sample), 
               names_to = "Time",
               values_to = "x") %>%
  dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.))
data
## A tibble: 80 x 4
#   Sample       y Time       x
#    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1      1 -0.449  Time1  0.768
# 2      1 -1.10   Time1  0.410
# 3      1 -0.529  Time1 -1.98 
# 4      1 -0.485  Time1 -1.09 
# 5      1  0.128  Time1  1.06 
## … with 75 more rows
```

Now that we have the data in the correct form, we can `facet_wrap` by Time:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  xlab(element_blank()) + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Time), rows = vars(Sample), scales = "free",switch = "both") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
           plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside", strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Note that there is no way to have a free y-axis within the same row nor free x-axis within the same column.

Comment: I need to preserve Time1 and Time2, so I don't think a facet wrap would work.

Comment: I would like for the figure to resemble the second figure in my post. In that figure, the two plots in the left column both have the same x-variable - Time1, and the two plots in the right column both have the same x-variable - Time2. All four plots have the same y-variable - Temperature. Maybe it would be helpful to think of the top row as coming from one field site and the bottom row coming from a second field site. Thank you for your help with this issue and please let me know if I can provide any further clarificaiton.

Comment: As long as you're not totally set on free x and y-axes you can use `facet_grid`. See my updated post.

Comment: The updated code is essentially everything, but I can't seem to get the x-axes title labels (Time1 and Time2) to look the same as the y-axis title label (Temperature). I've tried including `base_size = 16` in the `theme_bw()` command, and including `axis.title = element_text(size = 16)` in the `theme()` but both have not worked. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Try adding `strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16)` to your `theme()` call. This works because those labels are actually the facet "strips" that are being forced down there with a blank background.